# How do I save checkmarks that disappear when scrolling in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm pretty new to Swift and I'm working on my first app. I'm currently using the UITableView that has an option for checkmarks to appear on the right when users tap on it. It works fine but whenever you scroll down on the list of items, the checkmarks disappear. I've checked a few online sources but I'm unsure of how to apply it to the code I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, is there any way that I can store the checkmarks for when the user reopens the app? Every time I restart the app, the list of checks resets.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "celltwo")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Yes you can store it in core data/user defaults/any other online or offline option, but user defaults might be the easiest to implement. But it is best to not save it by index of switch but by some identifier which will not change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cell `accessoryType` disappears because the reusability feature the `UITableView` use, in order to keep the selection follow the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "celltwo")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    if let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    {
        if (paths.contains(indexPath))
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{

    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
    //remove deselection
    //tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Regard saving the selection, this info I guess should be persisted with your datasource in CoreData or UserDefaults.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong. `didSelectRowAt` needs to update the data model and then it needs to tell the table view to reload the row.

Comment: @maddy the question was not mentioning anything about the dataSource to save the state of the selection, hence I suggested saving the state through tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows which got reset when calling tableView.reloadData().
at the end of the Answer I mentioned that he can save the selection through a persistence storage available as he want to keep the selection after the app is killed.
in what terms did u find that the answer is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The checkmarks are disappearing on scrolling because table views reuse the cells so the 'cellForRowAt' method gets called whenever you scroll and you haven't provided the logic to show/hide the checkmark in this method. To solve this you can do the following,

1. Initialise an Array to store the indexes of the selected cells.

   ```
   var selectedIndexes : [Int] = []
   ```
2. Update your 'didSelectRowAt' method with the logic to add/remove indexes to/from the 'selectedIndexes' array.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
   {
       tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

      let indexOfItemToRemove = self.selectedIndexes.index(of: list[indexPath.row])

      self.selectedIndexes.remove(at: indexOfItemToRemove)

   }
   else
   {
       tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

    self.selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)

   }

   }
   ```
3. Update your 'cellForRowAt' method with the logic to show/hide checkmark.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "celltwo")

    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

   if self.selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row)
   {
    //cell was selected earlier
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

   }else
   {
    // cell was not selected earlier
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

   }

    return cell
   }
   ```

In order to save the selection for the next time the app is launched you could save the 'selectedIndexes' array to UserDefaults. In order to achieve this do the following :

1. Update the 'didSelectRowAt' method to include the logic to save the selected index to UserDefaults. At the following code at the end of the method.

   ```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(selectedIndexes, forKey: "SelectedIndexes")
   ```
2. Add the following code to the 'viewDidLoad' method.

   ```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    self.selectedIndexes = userDefaults.value(forKey: "SelectedIndexes")
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. With your code, this solves the problem with the scrolling however when I tap on a checked item, it freezes the screen as opposed to unchecking the task as before

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my answer with the right logic for removing the item from 'selectedIndexes' when unchecking. Update your 'didSelectRowAt' method with the changes I have made.